# Login via AJAX, no errors but no results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I have this code:

```
<form name="login" class="login-form" action="" method="post">
    <h2>Log In</h2>
    <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
    <input type="text" id="login-username" placeholder="Full Name" />
    <input type="password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password" />
    <button onclick="submitLogin();">Log In</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitLogin() {
        username = $("#login-username").val();
        password = $("#login-password").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data: "name=" + username + "&pwd=" + password,
            success: function(html) {    
                if (html == 'true') {
                    //$("#add_err").html("right username or password");
                    window.location="dashboard.php";
                }
                else {
                    $("#error").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
                    $("#error").html("<img src='images/alert.png' />Wrong username or password");
                }
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#error").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
                $("#error").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...")
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

This is login.php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';

    session_start();
    $uName = $_POST['login-username'];
    $pWord = md5($_POST['login-password']);
    $qry = "SELECT usrid, username, password FROM users WHERE username='".$uName."' AND password='".$pWord."'";
    $res = mysql_query($qry);
    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($res);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    if( $num_row == 1 ) {
        echo 'true';
        $_SESSION['uName'] = $row['username'];
    }
    else {
        echo 'false';
    }
?>
```

When I click login the page seems to reload or at least update. There are no errors but also there is no success. For the life of me can't work out whats wrong. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused, you seem to have the same AJAX call in two different files?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks! I accidentally put the `JS` code instead of the contents of the PHP file. Edited!

Comment: @KriiV try to alert the output of jquery ajax

Comment: As an aside, don't use MD5 for password hashing. Use a salt and a strong hash instead, such as PHP's crypt().

Comment: @pascalhein thanks. I will implementing a salt and stronger hashing later, trying to get basic functionality running first.

Comment: Just to remind, if there is any ajax problem - always first try all callbacks (error, success, always) and all methods (both callbacks as one of ajax function arguments `$.ajax(..., success: function(){}, ...)`and as separate methods `$.ajax(...).done(...)`

Comment: in the login.php, try echoing the `$uName`,`$pWord` and check you got the data assigned to it, then check the What `$num_row` returns

Comment: try this way to send data,`data : { foo : 'bar', bar : 'foo' }`

Comment: @pascalhein Or even better : http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
I've taken your code and worked with it a little bit. Here is what I found:

First of all - your page gets refreshed after form submit right?
You have to disable the defaul form submission event, for example like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

What this does is - it catches the default submit event , as 'ev' variable, and prevents it from firing.

This should stop your page from refreshing.

the next thing - be sure to check your ajax.url variable - does it really target the correct file in the correct folder ?

The rest of the code looks good - I managed to get a proper responce in my tests.

Try it, and come back with a feedback.

**// old message below **

You send the ajax request with:

```
$.ajax(
  data: "name=" + username + "&pwd=" + password
```

But in the login.php you are asking the POST for

```
$uName = $_POST['login-username'];
$pWord = md5($_POST['login-password']);
```

This is most probably causing some incostencies.
Try changing that first, to:

```
$uName = $_POST['name'];
$pWord = md5($_POST['pwd']);
```

And also, add the error handler to your ajax request:

```
error: function(responce){
    alert(responce);
}
```

I personally prefer to console.log(responce) - easier to debug for me

Comment: @KriiV - please take a look at this anwser

Comment: @wick3d Thanks. Doesn't work.  Only empty fields produce the wrong username or password error. Everything else does nothing

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
try this (you had an error in the script):

```
function submitLogin() {
        username = $("#login-username").val();
        password = $("#login-password").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data: "name=" + username + "&pwd=" + password,
            success: function(html) {    
                if (html == 'true') {
                    //$("#add_err").html("right username or password");
                    window.location="dashboard.php";
                }
                else {
                    $("#error").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
                    $("#error").html("<img src='images/alert.png' />Wrong username or password");
                }
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#error").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
                $("#error").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...");//error was here
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: sorry i didnt see it in time :(

Comment: The alert doesn't run.

Comment: then there is an error in jquery code or the url is incorrect let me see

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work. Only empty fields produce the `wrong username or password` error. Everything else does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that this is probably meaningless, but I usually recieve values (asp mvc) with capital letters.

```
if (html == 'True') ...
```

If this was the problem, then your else clause should be executing, and interesting enough you are using a ID selector '#error' , but in the html code the error is of class error, so the selector should be '.error' ... Its not probably from that but still ...